# Teffilin during Shabat

Tags: women, tefilin

[Semag](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21359&st=&pgnum=44) :

> כל אחד מישראל אינו יהודי שלם אלא אם כן יש לו שני עדים שהוא יהודי, הלכך בשבת ויום טוב שנקרא שבת, ושבת נקרא אות, פטור אדם מלהניח תפילין כי די שיש לו שני עדים שהוא יהודי עדות שבת ועדות מילה

(Rough translation)
*Everyone of Israel is not a 'complete' jew unless he has two proofs he is a jew. Therefore, during Shabat, and Yom-Tov which is called Shabat, and Shabat is 'Ot' (proof), he is exempt of wearing Tefilin since two proofs are enough.*

So, assuming women do wear Tefilin, would they need to do so during Shabat as well since they do not have the 'Ot' of Millah, or not.

Comment: A couple of possibilities: 1. Each Jew has two "witnesses" whenever there are two signs that collectively apply to the Jewish people. Women are included in the collective sign of *milah* even though it doesn't apply to them on an individual basis (per [*Mishna B'rura* 187:9](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A4%D7%96#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.92)). 2. As women can't have two individual "witnesses" during the week, it seems the need for signs only applies to males.

Comment: This question is already asked regarding someone who never got a bris milah because his brothers passed away from the circumcision. The answer is he is not chayav to wear on shabbos.

Comment: Just to clarify: As indicated by @Mefaresh, we clearly follow the opinion that t'fillin simply does not apply on Shabbos (*Eruvin* 96a, *M'nachos* 36b). The *S'mag* was talking in a טעמי המצוות sense rather than a halachic sense, so I was suggesting along those lines either that women have "two *eidim*" in the collective sense that *milah* and *t'fillin* apply to the Jewish people, or that women have no individual need for "two *eidim*." Either way, the *S'mag* is speaking homiletically, as the "*os*" exposition of the Talmud does not extend exegetically to a need for two at once.